# compare >= columns, then lstrip another column based on compare, subtract 1 and do until condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, series, strip

slowly but surely I'm learning this Python/Pandas but most of the time it wrangles me and twist me all over the place. I'm working on a project that will compares two columns (one row at a time) and then apply the operation of lstrip on another column in that same row. Basically, if [count column] is greater than [column1] then lstrip [column2 (any numbers and/or .periods) ], then lstrip [column2 ('|') one time, then subtract 1 from the [count column] and start the process over again. This should go on until the 'count' column number is equal to the 'column1' number then stop. But all fields in 'column2 have different number lengths and some will run longer than other fields.

Currently, the code will run and lstrip all rows (at the same time) in 'column2' and subtract 1 from all rows in the 'count' column. It will keep going until 'count' column reaches into the negative numbers. Meaning it doesn't stop the operation (for that row) when the 'count' column is equal to the 'column1'.

My thought is to handle one row at a time and when the 'count' column is equal to column1 then proceed to the next row down and start the process over again. Rinse & Repeat until done.  However, while trying to find examples I found the following link stating that pandas is designed to run the entire series(column) through the operation at one time versus my thinking of one row at a time logic.

```
<http://shorturl.at/acvIL>
```

I appreciate anyone that can help teach a man to fish.  Thanks for your time and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np

# get starting excel file - Working
df = pd.read_excel("E:\Book11.xlsx")

# inserts 'count' column  into last position. - Working
df.insert(2, 'count', '')

# counts the number of '|' spec-char in the 'col2' column and places sum into 'count' column . - 
# Working
f = df['column2'].str.count('\|')
df.loc['column2'] = df['count'] = f

# compares 'count' column number greater than 'column1' number to start condition
for count, column1 in zip(df.iloc[:, 2], df.iloc[:, 0]):

# if condition is true, then lstrip any (0-9.)chars, then lstrip('\|') spec-char,
# then subtract 1 from 'count' column and test again (all rows).
    df['column2'] = df['column2'].astype(str).str.lstrip('0123456789.')
    df['column2'] = df['column2'].astype(str).str.lstrip('\|')
    df['count'] = df['count'] - 1



# 'count' column has different numbers than 'column1' column so some rows will complete
# sooner than other rows. But all rows at different times and only if 'count' column reaches == 
# (equal) to 'column1' column .

print(df)



Before:
column1   column2                                                        count
7         0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0                                  14
2         369|369|219|219|219                                            4
3         413.1|413.1|413.1|413.1|413.1|413.1                            5
6         228.65|228.65|228.65|322.15|322.15|322.15|228.65|228.65        7
4         359|359|359|359|359                                            4


Finished Product:
column1   column2                                                        count
7         0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0                                                7
2         369|369|219                                                    2
3         413.1|413.1|413.1|413.1                                        3
6         228.65|322.15|322.15|322.15|228.65|228.65|225                  6
4         359|359|359|359|359                                            4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of performing the logic multiple times you could do it in one shot with `apply` and a `lambda` function. The idea is to split on `|`, and then join everything back again after slicing based on `column1`.

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].astype(int)
df['column2'] = df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.column2.split('|')[:x.column1 + 1]), axis=1)

   column1                                           column2  count
0        7                                   0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0      7
1        2                                       369|369|219      2
2        3                           413.1|413.1|413.1|413.1      3
3        6  228.65|228.65|228.65|322.15|322.15|322.15|228.65      6
4        4                               359|359|359|359|359      4
```

Comment: Hey ScootCork, Looking at this now. I like this ideal..!   I replaced the last three lines (just above print(df) and deleted the df['columns'] lines and received an error. Assuming that is where it goes? Error:TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method..  This makes me feel like the excel sheet is coming over as string or something else. The error reads must be integer so how can I test for this?  What your thoughts?

Comment: So looking at the excel file coming across in both the column1 and count columns there are decimal points followed by six zeros after the numbers.  I'm reading how to changes these over to integer currently so I can run your code.

Comment: Adjusted the answer for the cxast to int, you don't actually need the count as well so simplified it a bit.

Comment: ScootCork, can I send you a small sample of the original data. Excel file DF on sheet1, sheet2 the code.  I believe I'm not giving you accurate info about the DF but with the original you should see what is happening. Please let me know. I have a link for you when ready.   Look it over when you have time. I do appreciate the help. Thank You.
shorturl.at/nzCKU

Comment: Given your question this is a possible solution, if it doesn't work please make clear why it doesn't work or adjust/clarify your question. It is best to have a minimal reproducible example. This way others with similar problems are also helped.

Comment: Good Day to you ScootCork, I believe strongly that you have this question under control and have solved it. It's me that is trying to learn how things work. I agree that you need a reproduced example which is why I placed a link to an excel file in the above comment above this one. The problem seems to point to column 2 and might be because of the data type of the column. Please take a look. And let me know if your fix works on the example. I really appreciate the knowledge you have on this and have opened my eyes to a new way of thinking.

Comment: ScootCork,  I was able to get this working with the original DF.  It would have been nice to know that the entire code I had written was irrelevant and not needed and we could have avoided this back and forth. However, after spending some time trying to understand lambda & apply I began to decipher your code. The problem actually was my code of counting the '|' and str statement within the count column.  Your code couldn't change the column2 to integer.  So I got rid of my code altogether and only used one line of your code with a little adjustment.  Thanks for opening my eyes to smtg diff.

Comment: Hello ScootCork, Hope this note finds you well.  I wanted to ask about your lambda solution to this problem. I did exactly what I had asked for however, My question did not state it need to remove from the left side of string.  I'm sorry, My Bad. Can your lambda line be adjusted to pull from the left instead of the right? If you would like I can ask it in another question. But wanted your advice.